# Does Localization has nothing to do with the range of laser?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working with ROS kinetic in Ubuntu 16.04.

I just made a map following the [g-mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping), with Hokuyo's LiDAR of [UBG-04LX-F01](https://www.roscomponents.com/en/lidar-laser-scanner/115-ubg-04lx-f01.html).

And I wonder if the angle ranges when making the map can be different from those when real driving.

Do the angle ranges have nothing to do with localization itself?

Would there be no problem if the sensor has different angle ranges from those of gmapping?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382002/does-localization-has-nothing-to-do-with-the-range-of-laser?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-08**:
Please edit your title to make it match the actual question: change "range" to "angle range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The lidar angle range can be different between gmapping and "normal" navigation. They are independent. Once you have a map that is accurate, that map can even be used by other robots, even those having other types of sensors (e.g. ultrasonic range finder.)

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2021-07-08**:
Thank you, I'll try then. :)